# Server Side Event for Floodlight tags

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side, google-floodlight

We are using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to host all the tags including Floodlight tags. One of our conversion events can happen offline and hence, we are thinking to use Measurement Protocol to send the conversion events for GA4. It is working great so far. However, we also need to send that event to Floodlight tags and we are not sure how it is possible to do it.

We are exploring Server Side Tagging in GTM and saw an official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/fl-setup). However, it seems that the trigger needs to be online (or some sort of browser). I don't think Measurement Protocol call from backend server can trigger this event to record the conversion in the Floodlight tags.

Has anyone faced this issue before and what would be the ideal solution? Thanks!